# wso2 Developer Studio 3.7.1 Proxy Service GUI

Tags: xml, xslt, proxy, wso2, wso2-esb

I am working my way through the Banking Sample application at [wso2 banking sample](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS310/Retail+Banking+Sample#RetailBankingSample-CreatingMockObjectstorepresentLegacySystems)  Things have gone as written until the CardAxis2Service Proxy creation using a .xml document provided in the sample.

My Dev Studio displays the ESB graphical view for the proxy service (proxy service icon) and a standard properties table. This view shows in the JAVAEE and the ESB Graphical perspectives.  The wso2 example shows an explorer tree for the graphical view(design tab) of the proxy xml and the standard properties table in the J2EE perspective.

The directions require a right click on the In Sequence node in the explorer tree to create a child node and add an xslt document(also provided) to the proxy service.  I cannot find any way to make this happen using the ESB graphical view.

I have no problem with manually editing the file if I could find what I should add.  The proxy .xml document does have the In Sequence node. My vm is java_ee_sdk_6u3_jdk7/jdk7/jre/bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After entering the search query

> developer studio 3.7.1 banking sample

into google, I was directed to a banking sample document that showed how to do it using the latest developer studio.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS371/Retail+Banking+Sample#RetailBankingSample-CreateProxyServicestoabstracttheCardsSystem